# ROS Noetic xacro issue - Cannot load command parameter [robot_description] returned with code [2]

Tags: ros, urdf, xacro, turtlebot3, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**OS:**                Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
**Kernel:**           Linux 5.13.0-35-generic
**Architecture:**  x86-64
**ROS distro:**   ROS Noetic

I am trying to launch my turtlebot3 for a school assignment in the gazebo simulator using the following command:

```
roslaunch rob521_lab3 turtlebot3_world.launch
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
substitution args not supported:  No module named 'defusedxml'
when processing file: /home/sug/catkin_ws/src/rob521_lab3/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf.xacro
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '--inorder', '/home/sug/catkin_ws/src/rob521_lab3/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf.xacro']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find rob521_lab3)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have been trying to search various other forums and threads and most say to modify the .launch file relating to the parameter for "robot description".  However, I was unable to modify the launch file param line in any way that resulted in successful launch.

Here are my **ROS Environment Variables:**

```
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sug/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/sug/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=noetic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397871/ros-noetic-xacro-issue---cannot-load-command-parameter-%5Brobot_description%5D-returned-with-code--%5B2%5D/) by [sugumarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/100095/sugumarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, the solution was a very basic one and solved with one line:

```
pip install defusedxml
```

Now, it is working.  I was going too deep into deprecation of xacro from kinetic/melodic to noetic.

---

Originally posted by [sugumarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/100095/sugumarp/) with karma: 16 on 2022-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0